# If $A \neq B$ and $A×E=B×E$, then $E=\emptyset$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Prove (or provide a counterexample for) the statement If $A$ and $B$ are not equal, but $A×E=B×E$, then $E=\emptyset$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you written out what happens for small $A,B?$  Consider an element that is in one and not the other.

Comment: So I know that the identity of any set crossed with an empty set, results in an empty set so as long as A and B are not equal then this holds true but I don't know if E necessarily has to be equal to the empty set of this to hold true

Comment: Well, $~A\times E=B\times E~$ is defined as $~\forall x\forall y~((x\in A\wedge y\in E)\leftrightarrow (x\in B\wedge y\in E))~$. Now when $E$ is empty, this is *vacuously true*, but should we suppose $E$ is not empty, then this being true implies...

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$A \neq B $ implies (without loss of generality)  $a \in A$, but $a \notin B$

If $E \neq \emptyset$ then $e \in E$ for some $e$

Now

$(a,e) \in A \times E$ but $(a,e) \notin B \times E$